# How to launch mysqldump.exe in java independently on mysqldump.exe location?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to backup mysql database with java.

And I want to launch mysqldump.exe **independently** on location of mysqldump.exe.
To launch mysqldump.exe I need to write full path to it :

```
String executeCmd = "D://mysql-5.6.11-win32/bin/mysqldump -u "
```

Don't you know how to get rid of full path.
Maybe there is a way to get the path to `mysqldump.exe` having all connection details.
How do you think can I launch mysqldump.exe without specifying its full path?
And If I can't, then how can I get the path to mysqldump.exe on computer without asking user to provide path manually.

If I try to use mysqldump without full path to mysqldump.exe I receive this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, Íå óäàåòñÿ íàéòè óêàçàííûé ôàéë
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at dbViewer.model.ConnectionManager.backupDB(ConnectionManager.java:273)
    at dbViewer.model.ConnectionManager.main(ConnectionManager.java:337)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Íå óäàåòñÿ íàéòè óêàçàííûé ôàéë
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:189)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 5 more
```

Thanks!

Comment: Executing `mysqldump` is not related to JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an environment variable, call it MYSQLDUMP_LOCATION for instance. And then just refer to it. In my example I defined an environment variable called CMD_LOCATION (Notice that you'll have to restart windows or it won't be found).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();

        final String CMD_LOCATION = env.get("CMD_LOCATION"); 

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD_LOCATION + System.getProperty("file.separator")+"cmd /c start cmd.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So in your case, you'll have to write

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(MYSQLDUMP_LOCATION + system.getProperty("file.separator")+"mysqldump -u");
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't know how user named its environment variable. Is it possible to  get location of mysql bin folder on computer after connection has been established?

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to define a environment variable? No, I don't think it's possible to get the location of mysql bin, that's unknown to the application and you'll need to get it from a external source, such a environment variable.

Comment: Probably it is needed to ask user about his mysql bin location.